# How to fix column does not exist error for column that exists in odoo

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11

I get this error when I try to install a particular custom module in odoo. here is the error.

```
 File "/home/akoh/Documents/erpsoftapp/odoo11/cbi_addons/sales_delivery_report/sales_delivery_report.py", line 101, in init
    ) """ % (self._table, self._select(), self._from(), self._group_by()))
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo11/odoo/sql_db.py", line 155, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo11/odoo/sql_db.py", line 232, in execute
    res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column o.d_name does not exist
LINE 10:                             o.d_name AS driver_name_sale_ord...
```

This is the code block which I suspect the error is coming from, I did not write the code but I am expected to work on it.

```py
def _select(self):
        select_str = """
                    SELECT                
                            o.id AS id,
                            o.id AS order_id,
                            o.name AS order_num,
                        o.date_order AS date_order,
                        o.state AS order_state,
                            partner.name AS name,
                            o.d_name AS driver_name_sale_order,
                            o.t_number AS v_licence_plate_sale_order,
                            o.amount_total as bags_value,
                            wh.way_bill as waybill_num,
                            wh.d_name as driver_name,
                            wh.t_num as v_licence_plate,
                wh.state as state,
                sum(whl.product_qty) as bags_qty
                """
        return select_str

@api.model_cr
    def init(self):
        # self._table = sale_report
        tools.drop_view_if_exists(self.env.cr, self._table)
        self.env.cr.execute("""CREATE or REPLACE VIEW %s as (
                %s
                FROM ( %s )
                %s
                 ) """ % (self._table, self._select(), self._from(), self._group_by()))
```

Comment: Does the `d_name` column exists in table using  `o` alias?

Answer (score 0):

`d_name` field is not present in the model which you have alias as **O**,

please double check or put your all code with `_select` , `_from`, `_group_by` functions.